# Quartz Scheduler trigger are stuck

Tags: quartz-scheduler

We've got a problem with stuck triggers in an application using Quartz Scheduler version 1.8.6 when jobs do not complete.

For example, we have jobs with ssh calls or database queries. If these jobs hang (because the ssh call does not terminate or the select statement has a table lock), then I cannot get the jobs to trigger any more. The triggers are stuck until I forcibly restart the scheduler.

I have tried to Scheduler.interrupt(trigger) and Scheduler.rescheduleTrigger(). I have tried removing the trigger and recreating it. I have removed the job and recreated it.
The result is the same: I can restart the job, but the trigger hangs and is not run again.

Comment: Can you show us your trigger and job source code please ?

Answer (score 1):

Please disregard this question. I had problems with my installation which were unrelated to Quartz.

Scheduler.interrupt() is the correct method, and is working perfectly for me now.